# R ggplot horizontal bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

please I'm having really hard time to probably do something quite simply. I read different posts in here but can't find anything similar to what I would need.
I have the following dataframe:

```
sector <- c("tech", "energy", "retail", "gaming")
curr_sales <- c(10, 18, 15, 7)
avg_sales <- c(8.2, 20.1, 25.0, 4.1)
df <- data.frame(sector, curr_sales, avg_sales)
df$sector <- as.character(df$sector)
```

my initial goal was to create a plot with horizontal bars, with on the Y axis the sector, on the x axis the current sales `curr_sales` and bars sorted by current sales.
The following code so far helps to achieve this goal:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(sector, curr_sales), y = curr_sales)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

Goal: at this point, I would need a way to display for each sector (= for each horizontal bar) the average sales value. I was hoping to achieve this without having a second bar for each sector, but rather a marker or a line that would allow easily to see where the avg sales is per sector vs the current sales value.
I couldn't find any similar example and any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be able to do this with two geom_bar layers, each with a different y aesthetic.  Something like:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = reorder(sector, curr_sales), y = curr_sales), fill=sector) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = reorder(sector, curr_sales), y = avg_sales), alpha=0, color='black') + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("energy"="red", "gaming"="blue", "retail"="orange", "tech"="green"))
```

And you could play with the second bar to get the exact effect you are looking for (in my example it is transparent with a black outline).  This example also has colors.

Comment: wow!!! that's perfect! Please, and feel free not to answer, could you also suggest how to customize the color of the curr_sales bars? Thank you so much and have a great weekend!

Comment: I just updated it to show how to add colors.  Its really no problem - I've gotten tons of help here on stackoverflow.  One way to show your appreciation is to click the check bar to select the correct answer, if the answer addresses your question.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I wonder if, still related to your solution above, you would know how to add to the legend the fact that "curr_sales" is "filled color" and "avg_sales" is in "black". Thank you

Comment: I don't know that off the top of my head.  Searching for something like "legend for each geom" might get you started.  If you can't find the result, I'd post it as a new question.